# Инициализация массива

Tags: c++

Как заполнить `std::array<int, N>` N одинаковыми константами при инициализации?

Comment: Обязательно при инициализации, родной метод `fill()` не устраивает?

Comment: @PinkTux методов много, инициализация одна...

Comment: Sorry, я не понял глубокомысленности этого комментария :) Ну одна инициализация, и что? Как этот факт мешает воспользоваться методом?

Comment: @PinkTux никак,

Answer (score 6):

При помощи относительно несложной шаблонной магии, а именно, применяя *Variadic Templates* (шаблоны с переменным числом параметров), можно на стадии компиляции построить массив, содержащий требуемое количество одинаковых элементов.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// Контейнер для массива.
// numbers - список чисел для инициализации.
template<int... numbers> 
struct Array {
    using array = std::array<int, sizeof...(numbers)>;
    static constexpr array data { { numbers... } };
};

// Генератор.
// count - кол-во элементов.
// fill - число, которым будет заполнен массив.
template<unsigned count, int fill, int... numbers> 
struct Generator : Generator<count - 1, fill, fill, numbers...> { 
};

// Реализация, останавливающая рекурсию.
template<int fill, int... numbers> 
struct Generator<0, fill, numbers...> {
    using Data = Array<numbers...>;
};

// Проверка.
int main() 
{
    const unsigned N = 10;
    auto a = Generator<N, 42>::Data::data;
    for (int i : a)
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Comment: Хм, моё решение оказалось копией вашего. Удаляю.

Comment: За идею безусловно плюсану, но хотелось немного рефакторинга и форматирования. Избавиться от горизонтальной прокрутки (например, `template` и `struct` разнести по разным строкам), исключить путаницу с `N` и `data`, кое-где добавить `auto`, сделать make-функцию, возвращающую `Generator<N, 111>::data::data;`.

Comment: @alexolut Честно говоря, лениво. Перевёл ответ в общий.

Answer (score 4):

`std::arra<int,3> x{ 2,2,2 };`   :)

Разве что писать свое, типа

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T, int N>
class array_v: public array<T,N>
{
public:
    array_v(T x) { fill(x); }
};

template<typename T, int N>
void out(const array<T,N>& a)
{
    for(auto x: a) cout << x << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    array_v<int,100> a(5);
    out(a);
}
```

Comment: а если там 100 элементов?

Comment: Написать 100 чисел. Или написать производный класс с конструктором, вызывающим `fill`. не предусмотрен такой конструктор, который вам нужен, в этом классе...

Comment: `fill` может не работать в сценарии, если данные могут/должны попасть в ROM.

Comment: @Harry печально, я думал таплом можно

Comment: @VladD Боюсь, что инициализация в фигурных скобках в этом случае тоже не поможет.

Comment: @Harry: Я попробую какую-нибудь шаблонную магию, вдруг получится.

Comment: @VladD Удачи! Я не возьмусь - знаний/опыта для такого чуда, боюсь, не хватит...

Comment: @Harry: Оказалось проще: `constexpr`. Написал ответ.

Comment: `не предусмотрен такой конструктор` - более того, `std::array` вообще не имеет конструкторов, т.к. является агрегатным типом.

Comment: @alexolut Ну, конструкторы по умолчанию и копирования будут сгенерированы, так что эти конструкторы предусмотрены :)

Answer (score 0):

Если это надо в рантайме, то просто пишем вспомогательную функцию:

```
template<std::size_t N>
auto array_of_ints(int value) {
    std::array<int, N> a;
    a.fill(value);
    return a;
}
```

Если заполненный `std::array` нужен на этапе компиляции, то всё чуть сложнее. В действующем стандарте у `std::array` нет `constexpr` функций, по этому придется воспользоваться списком инициализации. Чтобы получить список инициализации нужного размера, можно распаковать `std::index_sequence`:

```
template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto array_of_ints_impl(int value, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::array<int, sizeof...(I)>{((void)I, value)...};
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto array_of_ints(int value) {
    return array_of_ints_impl(value, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Здесь `{((void)I, value)...}` превращается в `{value, ..., value}`, каст `(void)I` нужен чтобы подавить предупреждение компилятора.

Проверка: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7e823996011ef39